# Why does apply_filters behave different inside and outside a loop?

Tags: wp-query, loop, filters, the-content, oembed

**What I want**: the array of posts returned by creating `$query = new WP_Query($args);`

**Why**: to return specific content as a sort of API request in json format, ready to display on another site

---

**What I tried first**:

```php
foreach($query->posts as $post) {
    $post->post_content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
};
```

This performed the `autop` and `do_shortcode` filters correctly, but no the `oembed` transformation.

---

**What I ended up doing**:

```php
while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    $query->posts[$query->current_post]->post_content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());
endwhile;
```

The only difference in output, is that inside the loop it performs the oembed, outside it does not.  Where does this difference come from, and is there a better way I should have done this?

I checked `global $wp_filters` and `oembed` is definitely listed under `[8]`, so it wasn't a filter loading issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference because you are not using `the_post` function in the first example. What this function does is it calls `setup_postdata` function, which sets up all the globals needed for other functions to work. You can call it manually, just at the beginning of your `foreach` loop, like this: `setup_postdata( $post )`. In addition it is possible that you would also need to call a `global $post;` before your `foreach` loop.

Comment: $wp_filters is already a global variable.  How does setting up global post data affect `$var = apply_filters('filter_name', $value);`?

Comment: Well, the filter is loaded, but you don't know what exactly happens inside the filter. I have checked the `WP_Embed` class and it actually uses `get_post` function in numerous places. Now, if you check `get_post` function you will learn that it relies on global `$post` variable, which you haven't specified. The global `$post` is set during `the_post` function.

Comment: BTW, I haven't checked you code in action but just try to call `global $post;` before your `foreach` loop (or place `the_post();` at the beginning) and see if I am right.

Comment: Didn't test it fully, but it appears that you are right.  I don't understand why a function given a filter name and string as args can't apply the filters in the global wp_filter.  Iw guess that's because wordpress is still in transition to oo, so global references still matter. _sigh_

I ended up having to declare `global $more` inside the loop to display full articles anyway.  get_the_content only allows overriding of 'More...' text, but not wether to display it or not.